How to fix this problem: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to android.content.Context
The following error occurs when I try to execute the code and app also terminates. (Caused by:java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to android.content.Context)
I want to know how to fix it. Please tell me the way that can fix it.Thank you!
package com.example.scoremanagement

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        val scoreDao = AppDatabase.getDataBase(this).ScoreDao()
        val editTextMap = mapOf(
            R.id.editTextTestType to EditText(findViewById(R.id.editTextTestType)),
            R.id.editTextMathScore to EditText(findViewById(R.id.editTextMathScore)),
        )
        val score = viewModel.getScoreDetails(editTextMap)
        val saveScoreBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.saveScoreBtn)
        saveScoreBtn.setOnClickListener {
            thread {
                score.id = scoreDao.insertScore(score)
            }

        }
    }
}

xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="22dp"
                android:paddingRight="22dp"
                android:paddingBottom="22dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:text="请输入考试类型和各科分数并保存！"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:text="类型："
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextTestType"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="例：七上月考；八下期中；一模等"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="数学："
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextMathScore"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="例：119.5"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/saveScoreBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="保存分数"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


I want to know how to fix it.
Please tell me the way that can fix it.
Thank you!

The error java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to android.content.Context occurs because in your MainActivity you are trying to pass an EditText directly to the EditText constructor instead of the Context. This is happening in the following line:
val editTextMap = mapOf(
    R.id.editTextTestType to EditText(findViewById(R.id.editTextTestType)),
    R.id.editTextMathScore to EditText(findViewById(R.id.editTextMathScore)),
)


try for this
val editTextMap = mapOf(
    R.id.editTextTestType to findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTestType),
    R.id.editTextMathScore to findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextMathScore)
)


This way, you're passing the EditText reference obtained from findViewById to the map, rather than trying to create new instances of EditText.
